# When to use "ĉu" instead of "se"?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning

I became aware that `I don't know if he is friendly` should not be translated into

> Mi ne scias se* li estas amika

but into

> Mi ne scias **ĉu** li estas amika

But why? *Se* means "if", so why it is wrong in this case?

Comment: As an English-language proofreader, I'd want to use *I don't know whether he's friendly*.

Answer (score 20):

Simple rule of thumb - if you are able to substitute "whether" (I don't know whether he's friendly) then use "ĉu".

Answer (score 17):

The words following *se* provide the condition under which the other clause becomes relevant.

So, *Mi ne scias se li estas amika* means "If it is the case that he is friendly, then I do not know."

You need *ĉu* to express the fact that *scias* controls the other clause in the manner of *ke*.

(Note that *amika* is slightly stronger than the English *friendly*, which often just means *afabla*.)

Answer (score 7):

se - under the condition (that)

ĉu - whether (or not)

In your case it is a question of whether or not a person is friendly, and therefore the word to use is *ĉu*

The other phrase may be used, I suppose, in a very unusual context meaning something like "If he is friendly, then I don't know*.

"Kiu estas la malamiko en la libro?"

"Mi ne scias se li estas amika"

Answer (score 2):

They are both correct sentences, but the meaning is very different. But maybe it's a bit clearer with a different example.

- Ni scios morgaŭ, **ĉu** ŝi venos. = We don't know whether she will come or not, but tomorrow we will know.
- "Ĉu Lidia estas alta?" "Ni scios morgaŭ, **se** ŝi venos." = If she comes, we will know tomorrow whether she is tall. If she doesn't come, we will not know whether she is tall.

**An easy way to check:** If you can switch "if" out for "whether" in the English sentence without it changing its meaning, you should use "ĉu" in Esperanto.

---

It's also worth noting that using "ĉu" is consistent with sentences like "Mi scias, **kiel** mi povas fari tion", "Mi ne scias, **kie** estas la necesejo", "Mi komprenas, **kial** tio estas malbona ideo", "Mi volas scii, **kiom** manĝas elefanto", etc.

In Esperanto the second parts of the sentences all start with a question word, and are in fact usually perfectly fine questions if you just add a question mark. (Kiel mi povas fari tion? Kie estas la necesejo? etc.) So why should that be any different with "Mi ne scias, **ĉu** ŝi ŝatas min"?

We don't do that in English with "ĉu" (unlike e.g. "I don't know **where** the toilet is"), but I think that's just because, unlike Esperanto, English doesn't have a question word for yes/no questions. So instead we use "whether" or "if". But if English had one, we'd probably use it for this too. I do know that Japanese also uses its question particle in these cases, for example.

Comment: copy-pasta from https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/2551/about-%c4%89u-and-se-in-clauses