# About "ĉu" and "se" in clauses

Tags: word-choice, word-difference

Which one is correct? If both, what's the difference?

> Mi ne scias se ŝi ŝatas min.
>   Mi ne scias ĉu ŝi ŝatas min.

Mi legis ambaŭ tamen ĉu estas nuancoj?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are both correct sentences, but the meaning is very different. But maybe it's a bit clearer with a different example.

- Ni scios morgaŭ, **ĉu** ŝi venos. = We don't know whether she will come or not, but tomorrow we will know.
- "Ĉu Lidia estas alta?" "Ni scios morgaŭ, **se** ŝi venos." = If she comes, we will know tomorrow whether she is tall. If she doesn't come, we will not know whether she is tall.

**An easy way to check:** If you can switch "if" out for "whether" in the English sentence without it changing its meaning, you should use "ĉu" in Esperanto.

---

It's also worth noting that using "ĉu" is consistent with sentences like "Mi scias, **kiel** mi povas fari tion", "Mi ne scias, **kie** estas la necesejo", "Mi komprenas, **kial** tio estas malbona ideo", "Mi volas scii, **kiom** manĝas elefanto", etc.

In Esperanto the second parts of the sentences all start with a question word, and are in fact usually perfectly fine questions if you just add a question mark. (Kiel mi povas fari tion? Kie estas la necesejo? etc.) So why should that be any different with "Mi ne scias, **ĉu** ŝi ŝatas min"?

We don't do that in English with "ĉu" (unlike e.g. "I don't know **where** the toilet is"), but I think that's just because, unlike Esperanto, English doesn't have a question word for yes/no questions. So instead we use "whether" or "if". But if English had one, we'd probably use it for this too. I do know that Japanese also uses its question particle in these cases, for example.

Comment: Pardonon pro mia komento en Esperanto cxar mi estas pli memfida uzi Esperanto ol mia anglalingvo. Do resume, "se" cxi tie egalas al "kondicxe", cxu?

Comment: Cetere, jes, en cxinlingvo (mia gepatra lingvo) kaj japanlingvo trovigxas demandovorto por jes/ne-demandoj.

Comment: Jes, vi pravas. Malkiel la angla vorto "if", "se" en Esperanto ĉiam havas signifon, kiu similas al "kondiĉe de ..."

Answer (score 10):

They are both **gramatically** correct, but semantically, you'd never use the one with *se*.

- Mi ne scias ĉu ŝi ŝatas min.
- I don't know if/whether she likes me.

But

- Mi ne scias se ŝi ŝatas min.
- In the case that she likes me, I do not know.

Answer (score 4):

Ĉi tio estas ĝusta:

> *Mi ne scias **ĉu** ŝi ŝatas min.*

Ĉi tio **ne** estas ĝusta (kaj estas anglicismo):

> <s>*Mi ne scias **se** ŝi ŝatas min.*</s>

Fakte, eĉ en la angla, la dua frazo estus pli bona (laŭ mia scio), se oni uzas *whether*:

> *I do not know **whether** she likes me.*